# .Net XmlTextWriter: prevent replacing of > or < with &gt; or &lt;

Tags: xmltextwriter

I'm creating xml-like mark-up language using System.Xml.XmTextWriter that will be read by a third party app.

In this mark-up language, symbols > and < when inside an element, need to show up as, but the XmlTextWriter converts them to &gt ; and &lt ; (no spaces, I just added those because of formatting on here).

Any ideas on how to prevent this while still working with XmlTextWriter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can output raw XML (no escaping) with the XmlTextWriter.WriteRaw method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7sb8fsy.aspx

Comment: Chris, I've up-voted your answer because it is a good one (and taught me something I didn't know), but I may have misled you into assuming I needed the output to be valid xml, whereas it's just an xml-like mark-up language (hence the < and <). I've edit my post to clarify that, apologies...

Comment: @AndyHasIt - No problem.  If you need an invalid "XML" doc simply use a StringBuilder() to build it.

Comment: @AndyHasIt - almost forgot about the WriteRaw method.  I've updated my answer.